# SHOCKED by tile floors in a condo

Tags: electricity, electric-fields, everyday-life

I live on 10th floor if an old condo in South Florida. I have been getting shocked every time i step on floor. I need a cane and a walker. My floors are tiled. How or what device is there to help me prove that this electrical field is independent from. How do i stop it?

Comment: Do you have some sort of floor heating?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: For future reference we have a [diy.se] SE where this would likely be a better question.

Answer (score 2):

You have current flowing through the tiles somehow, probably from the mains through failed electrical insulation. This is not normal. It is dangerous. You need to call an electrician to sort this out.